# Nginx в location не выбирает значения по регулярному выражению

Tags: регулярные-выражения, nginx

Есть форма - она сабмитится к примеру на `/hello/test/complite`

в конфиге хоста прописан:

```
location ~ ^/hello/test/(complite|fail) {
    rewrite ^ index.php?action=$1 last;
}
```

Но в $1 ничего не попадает, хотя URL правильный и location срабатывает.
Если сделать

```
location ~ ^/hello/test/(complite|fail) {
    rewrite ^/hello/test/(complite|fail) index.php?action=$1 last;
}
```

то работает. Хотя другие location по такому же принципу выбирают значения по регулярке.

В чем может быть проблема?

UPD:
Помогло следующее.

```
location ~ ^/hello/test/(complite|fail) {
    set $action $1;
    rewrite ^ index.php?action=$action last;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В инструкции rewrite

```
rewrite regex замена [флаг];
```

*regex* -- это регулярное выражение, которое сопоставляется с URI запроса, и ссылки в *замене* ссылаются на то, что сопоставилось. Вы же отлавливаете URI с помощью location, а затем используете регулярное выражение **^**, в котором не на что ссылаться. $1 в этом случае будет работать вне инструкции rewrite, а в ней, можно сказать по аналогии с языками программирования, новая область видимости.

Во втором случае у вас нормальное регулярное выражение с группой (compile|fail), и ссылка $1 в *замене* работает нормально, ссылаясь на то, что сопоставилось с этой группой.

Comment: **Спасибо!** У меня таких rewrite очень много в конфиге хоста и я думал что значения будут браться из выборки location. Может в таких случаях(и их очень много) location вообще не имеет смысла?

Comment: Если все, что нужно сделать, -- это rewrite, то да, легко можно обойтись без location.

Comment: ещё раз спасибо :) Все очень понятно объснили.